# Variable in Blade using javascript

Tags: javascript, laravel-5, laravel-blade

In a script section within a view of laravel 5.4 I am using databatables to build up a datatable. In my route helper I'm trying to call a route with a score id. This score id is available in the javascript variable 'data' (tested it using console.log).

I would like to know how to get this variable to work.

```
//Works
var data = 1; 
$html = '@if(!is_null(Auth::user()) && Auth::user()->can('update-score'))<a class="btn btn-primary" href="{!! route('score.getHistoryScores', '1') !!}"><i class="fa icon-minus"></i> Verwijderen</a>@endif';

//Doesn't work
var data = 1;
$html = '@if(!is_null(Auth::user()) && Auth::user()->can('update-score'))<a class="btn btn-primary" href="{!! route('score.getHistoryScores', '+ data +') !!}"><i class="fa icon-minus"></i> Verwijderen</a>@endif';

//Doesn't work either and triggers error
//Error: Use of undefined constant data - assumed 'data' 
var data = 1;
$html = '@if(!is_null(Auth::user()) && Auth::user()->can('update-score'))<a class="btn btn-primary" href="{!! route('score.getHistoryScores', '' + data + '') !!}"><i class="fa icon-minus"></i> Verwijderen</a>@endif';
```

I tried several ways to achieve this, none of them worked.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are trying to assign a JavaScript variable in the server side.
try this,

```
$html = '@if(!is_null(Auth::user()) && Auth::user()->can('update-score'))<a class="btn btn-primary" href="{!! route('score.getHistoryScores') !!}/'+data+'"><i class="fa icon-minus"></i> Verwijderen</a>@endif';
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this solution:

```
$html = '@if(!is_null(Auth::user()) && Auth::user()->can('update-score'))<a class="btn btn-primary" href="{!! route('score.getHistoryScores', ':deleteId') !!}"><i class="fa icon-minus"></i> Verwijderen</a>@endif';
$html = $html.replace(':deleteId', data);
```

I added the :deleteId in the route. 
After that I replace this value with the desired javascript variable.